# Scala Seq's find - wrong number of parameters; expected = 1

Tags: scala

I have a Seq val that is populated with case class instances. I am then trying to use the `find` method in order to find the first option matching my criteria. Here is the code:

```
val week = weeks.find(now >= _.start && now <= _.end).headOption.map( _.week).getOrElse{0}
```

This is giving me an error:

```
wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
```

am I using the find method incorrectly above? The case class in the event it helps that `weeks` is populated with has the following definition:

```
case class Period(week: Int, start: DateTime, end: DateTime)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use `_` once per parameter, so scala thinks you're giving find a method that takes two parameters and it's telling you that it only takes a method with one parameter. This should work instead:

```
val week = weeks.find(p => now >= p.start && now <= p.end).headOption
                .map( _.week).getOrElse{0}
```

As a side note, you don't need to use `headOption` because `find` is already returning an option of the first instance that matches your predicate. Additionally, instead of `map` and `getOrElse` you should use a `fold` as it has much stronger type safety:

```
val week2 = weeks.find(p => now >= p.start && now <= p.end).fold(0)( _.week)
```

Comment: fold vs. map+getOrElse really doesn't have anything to do with type safety.  The compiler guarantees that they're both equally safe.  fold is just a little more compact. (Also, arguably, harder to read if you're unfamiliar...)

Comment: @dhg that is sadly not the case. `val thisIsBad = Option(5).map(_.toString).getOrElse(0)` will compile just fine and `thisIsBad` will have the type `Any` which is convenient because you probably won't know where you're error is coming from for a type `Any`. If you used a fold instead `val thisWontCompile = Option(5).fold(0)(_.toString)` you'll get a compile time error because a `String` is not an `Int`. Using `fold` is significantly better than `map+getOrElse` and in my opinion much easier to read but I am a bit biased since I am familiar.

Comment: Ah!  I see what you're saying.  Good point!  I'm still not sure I'd consider it more "safe", but I definitely agree that clear compiler errors are better than tracking down accidentally-introduced Anys.